# How to store all photos to one folder like in iPhone?

Tags: photos, file-management

iOS saved all photos in one folder, but Android saves them in different folders which is difficult to organize.

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3 with custom ROM 4.2 & using the QuickPic app for photos.

How to make Android save all photos in one folder?

Comment: More information is needed.  Which phone do you have and which Android OS version is it running?  Which app are you using to take photos?

Comment: added more info!

Answer (score 1):

Photo saving location is up to the individual apps.  Stock Android camera app, for example, always writes to SD Card's `DCIM\Camera` folder.  Other photo taking apps may have a different default location, but you should be able to change that in those apps' settings.

Various photo managing apps will try to scan your entire SD Card for images, and may pull in folders that belong to various other apps, not necessarily Camera/Camcorder.  Such apps usually have setting to specify which folders to include or exclude during such scans.